# Error adding raster to PostGIS: relation "<schema>.<table>" does not exist

Tags: raster, postgis, raster2pgsql

I just started using postgresql and PostGIS

This error doesn't seem to occur for anybody. I tried running the command to add a raster:

`raster2pgsql -s 27700 -I -C -M -t 256x256 path/to/my/raster.tif -d public.raster_test | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d spatial`

First, I get: `ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`

If I use `-e` this doesn't occur, but I still can't load the raster as I keep getting:

`relation "public.raster_test" does not exist`

I tried to change the client encoding to WIN1252, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62292306/import-raster-to-postgis-raster2pgsql-error) suggests, but no luck on that.

Comment: Your first error means that a statement is still trying to commit, first issue a `rollback;` with the user postgres and then try again. Also you could run raster2pgsql > out.sql to see what SQL sentences are being generated and if execute correctly one by one in a client program.

Comment: Thanks! I created the out.sql and found out there was an error before "ERROR: type "raster" does not exist". I then ran "CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster" in the database and everything worked fine.